# Poll Questions - Myth, Legend or Reality

Tags: discussion, support

There are some questions here on meta about poll questions but I'm not sure I've ever seen one on Stack Overflow or Stack Overflow Meta.

Do they exist on Stack Overflow or Stack Overflow Meta?

Did they ever exist?

Where did they go if they did exist?

I searched on here for Poll questions and there were mention of them but couldnt recall having ever seen one. I thought it may have been a specific type of question with a little graph and stuff. It just seemed the way folk were talking about them they may have existed as an actual type of question at one time.

Comment: How do you know there are some if you've never seen one?

Comment: I searched on here for Poll questions and there were mention of them but couldnt recall having ever seen one. I thought it may have been a specific type of question with a little graph and stuff

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: Check out the [meta-faq#vote-differences].  People tend to throw around downvotes alot here (on Meta), for a variety of reasons =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 I have noticed which is why I often avoid engaging - I have a genuine question asked in a polite manner but -5? Im not saying bring them back :p

Comment: Here's [a rev](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/406760/4) of a "historically significant" question that had the polls tag for about a month

Comment: "*I have a genuine question asked in a polite manner but -5?*" - Meta is a harsh mistress, indeed.

Comment: Meta rep is pretty much worthless.  If you ever want to add a bounty on a feature request you like, @me and (if I like it too!) I'll slap some on.  That's about all its worth.  Oh, and you might notice that you've gained 50 rep from this, but lost 16, as of this edit.

Comment: @Won't Thanks, I feel better now - Bizarrely I think I have more rep now than when I asked the question due to the amount of overall votes :) - However its not settled down yet!

Comment: Mysterious myth? Or Legendary Legend?

Comment: @BenBrocka Or Unfortunately reality

Comment: Is this another poll

Comment: Meta is very cliquish, very angry at times....just overall odd and scary.  Ignore the downvotes - this is a good question someone who's new here could reasonably ask.

Comment: +1, so I feel better about -1'ing you at some later date without just cause.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I searched on here for Poll questions and there were mention of them but couldnt recall having ever seen one. I thought it may have been a specific type of question with a little graph and stuff

I think you're misunderstanding what is meant by "poll question".

A poll question is any type of question which asks other users to pick one of multiple (possibly infinite) choices. There isn't a specific interface for this type of questions, nor are they wanted here. Poll questions solicit opinion and are – therefore – **not constructive**.

> Where did they go if they did exist?

Most (hopefully all) got locked, closed and/or deleted.

Comment: Thanks Dennis - I agree they are not constructive, It just seemed the way folk were talking about them they may have existed as an actual type of question at one time.

Comment: You should have just asked that. Until you added the comment I quoted, I never considered the possibility of a specific interface for poll questions. The downvotes make me assume that I wasn't the only one. Also: Tag support questions as `[support]`. Support questions (should) get downvoted less.

Answer (score 22):

> Do they exist on Stack Overflow / Meta?

No.

> Did they ever exist?

Yes.

> Where did they go if they did exist?

Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: The migration path to Yahoo! Answers was the greatest feature add ever.

Comment: Hmm. I could've sworn they went into the Google Buzz! Archives...

Answer (score 2):

> Where did they go if they did exist?

Most were deleted, meaning you can only see them if you have 10K rep.

A list of popular deleted questions—many of which are poll questions—can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list)

---

There's also [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/topprinted), which provides public access to most of these questions.

Just be very, very careful.  Opening up any of these questions can often result in *multiple* hours being wasted.